# Make scrollable table with 3 sticky columns to the left (without overlapping)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create table, that will contains sticky header and 3 sticky columns (on each row). To do this, I used position sticky attribute with predefined left attribute value. The main problem that I don't know how to fix, is to how determine valid values of each left attribute value (to make sure that when somebody start scrolling elements, columns doesn't overlpay each other)

Here is my html/css code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  
  table {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
  }
  th, td {
    padding: 0.25rem;
  }
  tr.red th {
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }
  tr.green th {
    background: green;
    color: white;
  }
  tr.purple th {
    background: purple;
    color: white;
  }
  th {
    background: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }

  th:first-child {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 12;
}

tr td:first-child {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 13;
}

tr td:nth-child(2) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 14;

}
tr td:nth-child(3) {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>HTML and CSS "Hello World"</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="red">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Job</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>URL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem.</td>
                <td>Ullam.</td>
                <td>Vel.</td>
                <td>At.</td>
                <td>Quis.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quas!</td>
                <td>Velit.</td>
                <td>Quisquam?</td>
                <td>Rerum?</td>
                <td>Iusto?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Voluptates!</td>
                <td>Fugiat?</td>
                <td>Alias.</td>
                <td>Doloribus.</td>
                <td>Veritatis.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Maiores.</td>
                <td>Ab.</td>
                <td>Accusantium.</td>
                <td>Ullam!</td>
                <td>Eveniet.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hic.</td>
                <td>Id!</td>
                <td>Officiis.</td>
                <td>Modi!</td>
                <td>Obcaecati.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Soluta.</td>
                <td>Ad!</td>
                <td>Impedit.</td>
                <td>Alias!</td>
                <td>Ad.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Expedita.</td>
                <td>Quo.</td>
                <td>Exercitationem!</td>
                <td>Optio?</td>
                <td>Ipsum?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Commodi!</td>
                <td>Rem.</td>
                <td>Aspernatur.</td>
                <td>Accusantium!</td>
                <td>Maiores.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Omnis.</td>
                <td>Cumque?</td>
                <td>Eveniet!</td>
                <td>Mollitia?</td>
                <td>Vero.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Error!</td>
                <td>Inventore.</td>
                <td>Quasi!</td>
                <td>Ducimus.</td>
                <td>Repudiandae!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dolores!</td>
                <td>Necessitatibus.</td>
                <td>Corrupti!</td>
                <td>Eum.</td>
                <td>Sunt!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ea.</td>
                <td>Culpa?</td>
                <td>Quam?</td>
                <td>Nemo!</td>
                <td>Sit!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Veritatis!</td>
                <td>Facilis.</td>
                <td>Expedita?</td>
                <td>Ipsam!</td>
                <td>Omnis!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vitae.</td>
                <td>Cumque.</td>
                <td>Repudiandae.</td>
                <td>Ut?</td>
                <td>Sed!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Accusantium.</td>
                <td>Adipisci.</td>
                <td>Sit.</td>
                <td>Maxime.</td>
                <td>Harum.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Can I acces to previous td/th table element and get current widht (so  I could setup valid value for left attribute), or there is some simples way which allows me to avoid situation when some elements starts overlaping?

Comment: This might help you: https://css-tricks.com/a-table-with-both-a-sticky-header-and-a-sticky-first-column/

Comment: @Azu this article describe situation when somebody want only 1 column to be sticky. In my case I need 3 columns to be sticky. The only solution that I already have in my mind, is to add dynamically specific style with left valid value attribute (but I really hope there is available more delightful solution with only styling tricks).

Comment: I have provided a working sample. However it's a bit tricky. For example the second column has 'left: 178px;' and 178px is the width of the first column. I've set the padding of 0, but you'll need to include it into the column width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  font-size: 125%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table thead th {
  padding: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}
table td {
  background: #fff;

  text-align: center;
}

table tbody th {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: left;

}
table thead th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
table tbody th {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
/**/
table thead th:nth-child(2),
tr td:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 178px;
  z-index: 3;
}
table thead th:nth-child(3),
tr td:nth-child(3) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 278px;
  z-index: 3;
}

table thead th:nth-child(2),
table thead th:nth-child(3){
    top:0
}

tr th:nth-child(2){
    left: 178px;
}
tr th:nth-child(3){
    left: 278px;
}
```

```html
<div role="region" aria-labelledby="caption" tabindex="0">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Teams</th>
        <th>Sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <th>abcd</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>Runs</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Milwaukee Brewers</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Los Angles Dodgers</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>New York Mets</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>St. Louis Cardinals</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Houston Astros</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Toronto Blue Jays</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Boston Red Sox</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Chicago Cubs</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Philadelphia Phillies</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Chicago White Sox</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>San Diego Padres</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Cleveland Indians</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>San Francisco Giants</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Cincinatti Reds</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <th>Minnesota Twins</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Tampa Bay Rays</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Miami Marlins</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Oakland Athletics</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Detroit Tigers</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Pittsburgh Pirates</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Seattle Mariners</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Atlanta Braves</th>
        <th>sample text</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is not correctly, because its assumes that data would be always the same. When you provide some elements in first table cell of row that would be bigger lenght that 178px, then you second will overlap first (when you scroll horizontaly)

Comment: This is what can be done only by CSS. Now you can use Javascript to determine the columns width and to make the table dynamic.

Comment: This might help you: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html